# GEF java draw2d Layout that adjusts to the width of the container so that it spans over more lines

Tags: eclipse, layout, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I need to show a line/multiline of images in GEF GraphicalViewer, so that it adjusts to the width of the container by spanning over more lines

Comment: can you elaborate the question. Looks like you are attempting a wordwrap, but I cann't get the container width part.

Comment: I have a row of buttons on a Panel. Yes, I want the same behaviour as they were a wordwrapped text that adjusts to the width of a text area when user shrinks it.

Answer (score 0):

[FlowLayout](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/draw2d/FlowLayout.html) is what you want.